# Is it possible to retrieve an #argument in a Powershell shell from within a program?

Tags: powershell, command-line, arguments

I am writing a program `prog.exe` that retrieves all arguments that are passed to it (in the form of a "sentence", not standalone arguments).

I just realized that in some cases only part of the line is retrieved, and this is when there are `#parameters`:

```
PS > ./prog.exe this is a #nice sentence
```

Only `this`, `is` and `a` are retrieved. In case I do not use `#` I get all of them. I presume this is because everything after the `#` is interpreted **by Powershell** as a comment.

Is there a way to retrieve **everything** that is on the command line?

If this makes a difference, I code in Go and get the arguments via `os.Args[1:]`.

Comment: Have you tried using quotes? Or are you asking how to tell the shell not to interpret comments as comments but as arguments?

Comment: @mkopriva: I realized that my example was not clear enough, I updated the question. As for your question: the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent PowerShell from interpreting `#` as a comment token by explicitly quoting the input arguments:

```
./prog.exe one two three '#four' five
```

A better way exists, though, especially if you don't control the input: split the arguments into individual strings then use the [splatting operator `@`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on the array containing them:

```
$paramArgs = -split 'one two three #four five'
./prog.exe @paramArgs
```

Finally, using the `--%` end-of-parsing token in a command context will cause the subsequent arguments on the same line to be passed *as-is*, no parsing of language syntax:

```
./prog.exe --% one two three #four five
```

Comment: I realized that my example was not clear enough, I updated the question. I think that your last solution will be a nice workaround (if I manage to create an alias that will allow me to not input manually `--%`)