# How to pass all arguments of a function to a program?

Tags: powershell, function, parameters, interpretation

Following-up on the last suggestion of a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75086216/903011), I am trying to find a way to disable interpretation of the parameters I want to feed to an executable

Since

```
D:\program.exe this is a #full sentence
```

will discard `#full sentence` as a comment (and I specifically do not want to use quotes), I was hoping that an intermediate function would fix the problem:

```
function global:note { 
  D:\program.exe  --% @Args
}
```

The rationale was that I do not want to interpret anything after `--%` **in the course of the execution of `program.exe`**, but still want to replace `@Args` **when running the function `note`** (as part of the execution of the function). Unfortunately, the result is a verbatim

```
D:\program.exe @Args
```

(the argument of `program.exe` is the string `@Args`)

My question: why isn't `@Args` expanded in the presence of `--%`, and the expansion happens without? Isn't `--%` supposed to stop the interpretation **of the command line** (i.e. do not interpret the command line for `D:\program.exe this is a #full sentence` when the arguments **of the function** are `this is a #full sentence`)

---

Following Matthias' comment on splatting, here is what I get in different scenarios:

### Case 1

```
function global:note { 
  D:\program.exe @Args
}
```

Output when typing `note this is a #complete sentence` at the PS prompt:

```
this is a
```

### Case 2

```
function global:note { 
  D:\program.exe --% @Args
}
```

Output when typing `note this is a #complete sentence` at the PS prompt:

```
@Args
```

Comment: Why _and I specifically do not want to use quotes_ ???

Comment: @Theo: this is a cli that is intended to quickly capture an input, and process/forward it further. The input will be natural language so I do not want to add extra elements such as quotes. Everything would have been fine if not for that `#` interpretation

Comment: `--%` stops parsing PowerShell syntax and treats the rest of the line as a literal string, so it of course also doesn't parse the `@`-operator and instead treats it as a literal. In any case, running the program through a function isn't going to make any difference here since the arguments are parsed/evaluated before they're passed to the function. Quoting the sentence is the best option. Or read it from stdin.

Comment: @jkiiski: *Or read it from stdin* oh yes - how could I have missed that. Too much backend dev I guess :) Thank you!

Comment: @jkiiski: would you mind turning your comment into an answer, and if possible just expand a little about how is `--%` interfering with `@Args`. I have a hard time understanding why the flow is not "I call a function with arguments A and B, they are passed to the function, expanded as A and B, and then the program is ran with `--% A B` which means that A and B will not be interpreted"

Comment: As an aside, why not just do `D:\program.exe @Args` (as suggested in the previous answer)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen because in such a case I would need to explicitly add `--%` as the first parameter of the command line (I mentioned in an earlier comment that *this is a cli that is intended to quickly capture an input, and process/forward it further. The input will be natural language so I do not want to add extra elements such as quotes*)

Comment: You don't need quotes when you're splatting. What happens when you just define the function as `D:\program.exe @Args`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I updated the question (at the very bottom) with the information you requested

Comment: That's a problem with how you _invoke_ the `note` function, the function itself works as expected. How are you receiving the input data in the first place?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I type in the shell prompt `note this is a #complete sentence` (`note` being the name of the function)